# Instruments does not catch undeleted objects when program terminates

Tags: c++, xcode, memory-leaks, instruments, xcode4.5

For the sake of demonstration, I have created this simple console application:

```
#include <iostream>

class Person {
public:
    int mAge;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Person *iPerson = new Person();
    iPerson->mAge = 15;

    std::cout << "Age: " << iPerson->mAge;
    return 0;
}
```

Now I'm aware that Valgrind and CPP Check will identify leaks here, but testing Apple's Instruments, When I profile this code I can't see any leaks. This is despite iPerson never being deleted.

Comment: On my machine valgrind correctly detects "definitely lost: 4 bytes in 1 blocks"...

Comment: What programs are you using? One doesn't even need a tool to see the leak...

Comment: @MFH - This is actually a simple case to demonstrate the fact that I don't get anything for objects that are not deleted. The actual problem involves a rather big framework and a test app. Because I don't get memory leaks for objects the test app does not delete, I also don't get memory leaks for the objects composed within these app objects, and so forth. I don't really see the point submitting hundrads of code lines, when the issue can be demonstrated with a dozen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaks Instrument performs snapshots at a predefined frequency. By default, that value is "every 10 seconds". You program completes before 10 seconds. Thus, the leak is never collected. So you must suspend execution after `iPerson` has gone out of scope in order for that leak to be detected. Also, if you just add a `sleep` while that pointer is still referenced on the stack or in a register, then it won't be a leak.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked it out:

- I had to set the snapshot interval to 1 second.
- I had to disable (set to None) Optimization for the release version (for which profiling is done).

Then based on justin's reply and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122617/memory-leak-checking-using-instruments-on-mac), I had to modify my code like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

class Person {
public:
    int mAge;
};

void CreateLeaks()
{
    // All three lines will generate a leak.
    Person *iPerson = new Person();
    iPerson = new Person();
    iPerson = new Person();
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    CreateLeaks();

    sleep( 2 );
    return 0;
}
```

There are still some odd things going on. For example, if you start adding `sleep(2)` within  `CreateLeaks`, Instruments doesn't catch all leaks (depending on where you put the `sleep` commands. Odd.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at [Tips for Improving Leak Detection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/FindingLeaks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001883-CJBJFIDD) from the Mac Developer Library.

[Cppcheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/) static analysis tool for C/C++ code might also help. For the example you provided, it finds:

```
#>cppcheck  so_code.cpp
Checking so_code.cpp...
[so_code.cpp:15]: (error) Memory leak: iPerson
```